# Packer SSH timeout when setting custom VPC, subnet and security group

Tags: packer, packer-builder

So I needed to be able to move my packer builders inside a private VPC and add a locked down security group that only allowed ssh from a restricted range of IPs, thus:

```
"builders": [{
"type": "amazon-ebs",
"associate_public_ip_address": false,
"access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
"secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
"region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
"source_ami_filter": {
  "filters": {
    "virtualization-type": "hvm",
    "name": "{{user `ami_source_name`}}",
    "root-device-type": "ebs"
  },
"owners": ["{{user `ami_source_owner_id`}}"],
"most_recent": true
},
"instance_type": "t3.small",
"iam_instance_profile": "{{user `iam_instance_profile`}}",
"ssh_username": "{{user `ssh_username`}}",
"ami_name": "{{user `ami_name_prefix`}}_{{user `ami_creation_date`}}",
"ami_users": "{{user `share_amis_with_account`}}",
"ebs_optimized": true,
"vpc_id": "vpc-123456",
"subnet_id": "subnet-123456",
"security_group_id": "sg-123456",
"user_data_file": "scripts/disable_tty.sh",
"launch_block_device_mappings": [{
  "device_name": "{{user `root_device_name`}}",
  "volume_size": 10,
  "volume_type": "gp2",
  "delete_on_termination": true
}],
"tags": {
  "packer": "true",
  "ansible_role": "{{user `ansible_role`}}",
  "builtby": "{{user `builtby`}}",
  "ami_name": "{{user `ami_name_prefix`}}_{{user `ami_creation_date`}}",
  "ami_name_prefix": "{{user `ami_name_prefix`}}",
  "project": "{{user `project`}}"
}
 }]
```

To start with I added "associate_public_ip_address:false" (false is the default as well) as every time I ran packer the host was assigned a public ip address but even adding that it still picks up a public ip????????

I used a security group that I had assigned to Jenkins build slaves which also communicate over port 22 and I haven't had any issue with accessing them from any part of my infrastructure.

I get this error:

```
1562344256,,ui,error,Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Timeout waiting for SSH.
1562344256,,error-count,1
1562344256,,ui,error,\n==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
1562344256,amazon-ebs,error,Timeout waiting for SSH.
1562344256,,ui,error,--> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

During the wait period for SSH to respond I was able to **nc -v 1.2.3.5 22** and I get a connection so the security group is allowing communications on port 22 from my IP address.

If I change the security group to **0.0.0.0/0** it connects straight away but why when I can **nc** to port 22 with the restricted security group can packer not initiate an SSH connection? Is packer trying to use the public IP address that I can not for the life of me turn off?

I thought it might be quite helpful to **tcpdump** the traffic on port 22 to see what was happening but I have a locked down laptop that does not allow the install of that particular handy item.

I can also ssh to the builder from my laptop but get a **Too many authentication failures** error and can't log in to see what is going on.

Comment: Pretty sure that packer is using the public ip/public dns to connect to the packer instance but I have turned off public ip address assignment. How do I really turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason that the packer builder is getting a public ip is down to the subnet settings - **map_public_ip_on_launch = true**.

So answer is build a new private subnet for the packer builder, build a new NAT GW in the public subnet then route from the private subnet to the NAT GW with a new routing table.